# Counter up jquery in dutch formate not working

Tags: jquery, counter

I am trying this plugin https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up

but when i try with the dutch number formate 2.000.00 then its giving NAN,

while i am tr 2,00,00 like this number formate then its working. any chnace to chnage in this code ?

```
// Preserve commas if input had commas
if (isComma) {
  while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(newNum.toString())) {
  newNum = newNum.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
 }
```

Comment: what about parsing your string to number for later use in the counter? parseInt() or parseFloat()

Comment: Use the number in the format which JS can work with then convert it to a Dutch formatted string output when displaying it. If you need an example of how to do this please add all relevant code in to the question

Comment: Thanks for helping i have tried but not working whole code is here https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/blob/master/jquery.counterup.js

Comment: I don't know anything about Dutch but JavaScript doesn't seem to think that `2.000.00` is what the Dutch locale looks like ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w54a09yo/)). To me that looks like [Indian separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system#Use_of_separators).